# replace symbol in javascript

Tags: javascript, quotes, quotation-marks

Does anyone know how can I replace this 2 symbol below from the string into code?

- '      left single quotation mark      into     ‘
- '      right single quotation mark      into     ’
- "      left double quotation mark      into     “
- "      right double quotation mark     into     ”

Comment: Did you mean for each of those those to be on their own line?

Comment: He wants to replace normal quotes with the "curly" ones.

Comment: OK. I'm going to reformat so it's easier to understand.

Comment: Does StackOverflow replace smart quotes for posted code? Do you have to use the HTML entities to get them to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing which way to make the quotes go (left or right) won't be easy if you want it to be foolproof. If it's not that important to make it exactly right all the time, you could use a couple of regexes:

```
function curlyQuotes(inp) {
    return inp.replace(/(\b)'/, "$1’")
              .replace(/'(\b)/, "‘$1")
              .replace(/(\b)"/, "$1”")
              .replace(/"(\b)/, "“$1")
}

curlyQuotes("'He said that he was \"busy\"', said O'reilly")
// ‘He said that he was “busy”', said O’reilly
```

You'll see that the second ' doesn't change properly.

Answer (score 1):

The hard part is identifying apostrophes, which will mess up the count of single-quotes.

For the double-quotes, I think it's safe to find them all and replace the odd ones with the left curly and the even ones with the right curly. Unless you have a case with nested quotations.

What is the source? English text? Code?

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a typography prettification engine called [jsPrettify](http://jsprettify.googlecode.com/) that does just that. Here's a quotes-only version the algorithm I use (original [here](http://jsprettify.googlecode.com/hg/prettify.js)):

```
prettifyStr = function(text) {
  var e = {
    lsquo:  '\u2018',
    rsquo:  '\u2019',
    ldquo:  '\u201c',
    rdquo:  '\u201d',
  };
  var subs = [
    {pattern: "(^|[\\s\"])'",      replace: '$1' + e.lsquo},
    {pattern: '(^|[\\s-])"',       replace: '$1' + e.ldquo},
    {pattern: "'($|[\\s\"])?",     replace: e.rsquo + '$1'},
    {pattern: '"($|[\\s.,;:?!])',  replace: e.rdquo + '$1'}
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < subs.length; i++) {
    var sub = subs[i];
    var pattern = new RegExp(sub.pattern, 'g');
    text = text.replace(pattern, sub.replace);
  };
  return text;
};
```